# SVG element in Adobe Xd appears below other element despite being higher in layers hierarchy

Tags: user-interface, svg, frontend, adobe, adobe-xd

In my **Adobe Xd** project my purple **SVG element** (pointed to in blue) **appears lower than a rectangle element** (pointed to in red) **despite being higher in layers column** (circled in green). The SVG was imported from a file on a Mac and gotten from Shutterstock.

[**Image of Adobe Xd Project**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0erT.png)